# Nav bar logo out of place HAML

Tags: html, haml

I'm creating a website called NoteIt (using `HAML`), where users can create notes, and only view the notes they've created. How do you select a `link_to` part to style it?

Here is my `application.html.haml` file:

```
!!!
%html
%head
  %title NoteIt | Your online Notebook
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags 
%body  
  %header
    .header_inner
      %h3 NoteIt << Here is where the NoteIt sign is placed 
      %nav
        -if model_signed_in?
          = link_to "New Note", new_note_path
          = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_model_session_path, method: :delete
        - else
          = link_to "Log In", new_model_session_path
  %p.notice= notice
  %p.alert= alert

  = yield
```

Comment: HAML is a tool to generate HTML. HTML is styled with CSS to give it an appearence. Where is your real problem? Generating the HTML that you want? Or styling the resulting HTML? Focus your question on that. Show us the HAML + actual HTML + desired HTM **or** show us  the HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. All you need to do is change the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, and set it to the desired amount of `px`. For the logo, I wrote NoteIt with an `h1` tag.